# WPF CrystalReports: How to rotate a report?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, crystal-reports, rotation

I have a wpf application with the crystal reports wpf control

```
<sap:CrystalReportsViewer
   Name="crystalReportsViewer"
   Width="auto"
   Height="auto"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   ShowPrevPageButton="False"
   ShowStatusbar="False"
   ShowToolbar="False"
   SourceUpdated="crystalReportsViewer_SourceUpdated"
   TargetUpdated="crystalReportsViewer_TargetUpdated"
   ToggleSidePanel="None" />
```

Now I want to rotate the report. As far as I know there is no built in function in the wpf control.

That is why my solution looks like this:

```
crystalReportsViewer.ViewerCore.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(90);
```

The problem here is that I can only perform one rotation, a second rotation fails. This means also that I can't rotate back to starting position... Any ideas?

Comment: how does it fail? error? not appear to change?

Comment: i have two rotations: 90 degree left and 90 degree right. when i rotate 90 degree left, i can't rotate left again... when i rotate the left rotated control to the right, it won't rotate 90 degree to the right, but 180 to the right... now i can not rotate right again. if i rotate left i will rotate 180 degrees left....

Comment: So its either 90 left or 90 right.. um.. just a thought what happens if you have like a bunch of options 0, 90, 180, -90 ? does it go all the way round?

Comment: i used 90 and -90 in my solution... when using 180 and -180 it rotates 180 degree to the left or to right, but in this case really one time... that means if i click rotation button twice nothing happens

Comment: you've missed my point, I think that if you write rotate(90) its not cumulative but just "move this to 90" so you can then press it all you like.. setting it to 0 would move it to normal, 180 upside down etc

Comment: that makes sense... so a matrix transform should do the trick?

Comment: maybe :) or just keeping tabs where you were and adding removing 90 :P